# Why is Apache http server logging a json POST response as binary?

Tags: json, apache, http

I'm trying to debug a call made from a Java desktop application to a Java server, which goes via Apache http server. The call is an http json call, I want to log the request and response on Apache. I have enabled the dump io module and can now see the request and response, but the response is formatted as binary:

```
16:58:10 GMT\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\nX-Content-Type-Options: 
nosniff\r\nReferrer-Policy: no-referrer\r\nbreadcrumbId: ID-machine-name-here-33747- 
1626280202382-10-673\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nSet-Cookie: 
JSESSIONID=88F411906EC0D; Path=/; HttpOnly\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nContent- 
Encoding: gzip\r\nSet-Cookie: ROUTEID=.1; path=/app-path\r\nContent-Length: 
61\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n

[Fri Jul 16 17:58:07 2021] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data- 
HEAP): \xabV\xaa\xc8\xcdQ\xb2R\xb2)JMK- 
J\xcdKNuI,I\x0cIL\xcaIuIM\xcb\xcc\xcb,\xc9\xcc\xcf\xd3\xb7S\xaa\x05
```

Why is this showing as binary? Is there a way I can get this logged as text?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this showing as binary?

Everything is binary, but the reason it's not showing as plain text is because this is the actual body that's sent, and the body is gzipped.

> Is there a way I can get this logged as text?

You could turn off gzipping.